# how to "preserve internal directory structure" when unzipping on windows?

Tags: windows, zip, archiving, 7-zip

I'm tring to build `boost`, in [instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html) I've read

`When you extract the library from its zip file, you must preserve its internal directory structure (for example by using the -d option when extracting). If you didn't do that when extracting, then you'd better stop reading this, delete the files you just extracted, and try again!`

The question is: How to unzip zip file and "preserve internal directory structure"? What program and how should I use? I have 7zip and Total Commander installed, can one of these programs "preserve internal directory structure"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the .zip file, select `7-zip` > `Extract files...`, and in the following dialog select the destination of the file extraction, making sure to select `full path` in the `folders structure` dropdown box.

This way, you are sure that the folder structure is preserved, anyway, I think that it is the normal behaviour even whit the simple extract command.

P.S. Please note that I'm not using the english version of 7zip, so the commands might differ a bit from what I've typed.